# How do I add a random number in a label?

Tags: c#, .net, random

I have put the following in the Form1_Load:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomNumber1Label = r.Next(1, 10);
```

But I am needing to get the random numbers to show up in the following labels:

```
randomNumber1Label
randomNumber2Label
```

Comment: It seems like you have variable name overlap between your integer which holds your random number and the label name. Is this true?

Comment: I changed it to that to see if it would help. Originally I had it as                
 Random r = new Random();
 int captchaNumber1 = r.Next(1, 10);

Comment: Its very hard to tell what you are trying to do, but using "Label" in a variable name (`randomNumber1Label`) doesnt make it a `Label`

Comment: `randomNumber1Label.Text = r.Next(1, 10).ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

You can display random numbers in your labels with the following code using the text property of the label.

```
Random r = new Random();

int randomNumber1 = r.Next(1, 10);
randomNumber1Label.Text = randomNumber1.ToString();

int randomNumber2 = r.Next(1, 10);
randomNumber1Label2.Text = randomNumber2.ToString();
```

Comment: When I debug it doesn't give me any errors, but the random numbers are not showing up either.

Comment: Are they showing some other value, or do they have the `Visible` property set to false?

Comment: They are just blank showing no value. The Visible property is set to true.

Comment: Can you put a default value into their `Text` property in the designer, so that you can see if it is working at all?

Comment: Yes, if I put a number into the Text property it does show up.

Comment: Can you please include your whole Form1_Load constructor in its current state to your question please?

Comment: I got it to work! I had it in the incorrect spot. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Deanna Fajardo if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.